# What are the ramifications of returning the value -1 as a size_t return value in C?

Tags: c, size-t

I am reading a textbook and one of the examples does this. Below, I've reproduced the example in abbreviated form:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

size_t linearSearch(const int array[], int searchVal, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    int myArray[SIZE];
    int mySearchVal;
    size_t returnValue;

    // populate array with data & prompt user for the search value

    // call linear search function
    returnValue = linearSearch(myArray, mySearchVal, SIZE);

    if (returnValue != -1)
        puts("Value Found");
    else
        puts("Value Not Found");
}

size_t linearSearch(const int array[], int key, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (key == array[i])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Are there any potential problems with this?  I know size_t is defined as an unsigned integral type so it seems as if this might be asking for trouble at some point if I'm returning -1 as a size_t return value.

Comment: Your code won't compile because you've not specified the type of `returnValue` in `main()`, but presumably it should be `size_t`?

Comment: Your compiler may legitimately decide to complain about comparing signed with unsigned — GCC will if provoked — but otherwise "it works".  On two's-complement machines (most machines these days), `(size_t)-1` is the same as `SIZE_MAX`.  It means that you can't distinguish between the last entry in the biggest possible array and not found, of course, but that's seldom an actual problem.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, This is pseudocode. Is complete working code necessary to answer the question I asked?

Comment: So, it's just the one edge case where I could end up having a problem?

Comment: Well, instead of three lines of comments, you could add two lines of working code to the search function, and then you'd only need to include the type of `returnValue` and … oh, there's the data for `myArray` and `mySearchVal` – no, you don't have to have fully compilable code but it would, IMO, still be sensible to specify the type of `returnValue`.

Comment: Yes, I realize I'd have to write all that out if I was trying to make this workable but I am not trying to write a program here. I'm just asking the question about returning -1 as a size_t value. I just wrote the minimum code for you to see what I was talking about.

Comment: Nominally, yes.  It would usually have to be an array of `char`, though, to be big enough to cause trouble — and while you could have 4 GiB memory with a 32-bit machine, it's pretty implausible (and it's very much less likely to be an issue with 64-bit machines; most don't run to 16 exbibytes of memory).  So it isn't a practical edge case.  So in practice it is OK, but the compiler warnings will be a pain.

Comment: size_t is unsigned so you can't check for < 0, you would have to check for the actual value. To an assembler coder, that's a real "yuck"!

Comment: This kind of situation is why POSIX introduced `ssize_t`.

Comment: It sounds like there is a better approach. How would you write the search function and define the return value?

Comment: @NateEldredge using `ssize_t` here would cut the maximum searchable size in half

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  `(size_t)-1` means `SIZE_MAX` on all systems. Out-of-range conversion to unsigned types is defined to wrap around.  It is only out-of-range conversion to signed types which may depend on 2's complement etc.

Comment: @M.M: You are right that `ssize_t` would cut the maximum size in half.  However, usually `size_t` is the same width as the address space, and on most systems you can't actually access the whole address space anyway.  This is particularly a non-issue on 64-bit systems, where nobody is going to have that much memory for a while.  (You can quote me on this: "9007199254740992K should be enough for anybody!")

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler may decide to complain about comparing signed with unsigned — GCC or Clang will if provoked<sup>*</sup> — but otherwise "it works". On two's-complement machines (most machines these days), `(size_t)-1` is the same as `SIZE_MAX` — indeed, as discussed in extenso in the comments, it is the same for one's-complement or sign-magnitude machines because of the wording in §6.3.1.3 of the C99 and C11 standards).

Using `(size_t)-1` to indicate 'not found' means that you can't distinguish between the last entry in the biggest possible array and 'not found', but that's seldom an actual problem.

> So, it's just the one edge case where I could end up having a problem?

The array would have to be an array of `char`, though, to be big enough to cause trouble — and while you could have 4 GiB memory with a 32-bit machine, it's pretty implausible to have all that memory committed to a character array (and it's very much less likely to be an issue with 64-bit machines; most don't run to 16 exbibytes of memory). So it isn't a practical edge case.

In POSIX, there is a `ssize_t` type, the signed type of the same size of `size_t`.  You could consider using that instead of `size_t`.  However, it causes the same angst that `(size_t)-1` causes, in my experience.  Plus on a 32-bit machine, you could have a 3 GiB chunk of memory treated as an array of `char`, but with `ssize_t` as a return type, you couldn't usefully use more than 2 GiB — or you'd need to use `SSIZE_MIN` (if it existed; I'm not sure it does) instead of `-1` as the signal value.

---

<sup>*</sup>
GCC or Clang has to be provoked fairly hard.  Simply using `-Wall` is not sufficient; it takes `-Wextra` (or the specific `-Wsign-compare` option) to trigger a warning.  Since I routinely compile with `-Wextra`, I'm aware of the issue; not everyone is as vigilant.

Comparing signed and unsigned quantities is fully defined by the standard, but can lead to counter-intuitive results (because small negative numbers appear very large when converted to unsigned values), which is why the compilers complain if requested to do so.

Comment: As I understand it, the C standard actually guarantees that converting negative numbers to unsigned behaves like two's complement, whether or not that's the machine's native format for signed integers. I think you should get `SIZE_MAX` in all cases

Comment: @NateEldredge: are you sure?  That would mean that one's complement and sign-magnitude machines are formally not supported (allowed) by the C standard, which seems unlikely — even though the overwhelming majority of modern systems are indeed two's complement systems.  Can you quote the section of the standard that makes you think that?

Comment: For the assignment, you do get `SIZE_MAX` in all cases, per §6.3.1.3

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: §6.3.1.3 "Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type."

Comment: Thanks @user3386109.  It's not that sign-magnitude, etc, machines are forbidden - just that when converting signed to unsigned integers, the compiler on such a machine can't just copy the bits - it's required to do arithmetic to emulate the two's complement behavior.  But the machine is totally free to represent signed integers any way it wants internally.

Comment: Regarding `ssize_t`, I don't think it's standard C.  It is specified by POSIX, though, and likely to be widely available.

Comment: I think the reason GCC and clang have to be provoked hard is because the behaviour is already well-defined by the standard, so a warning isn't all that legitimate.

Comment: @NateEldredge there are clauses that limit the choice to one of sign-magnitude, 1's comp, or 2's comp

Comment: C90, C99 and C11 all have sufficiently similar wording about promoting a signed integer value to a (larger or equal size) unsigned value. C90 said in §6.2.1.2 _Otherwise [if the value is negative]: if the unsigned integer has greater size, the signed integer is first promoted to the signed integer corresponding to the unsigned integer: the value is converted to unsigned by adding to it one greater than the largest number that can be represented in the unsigned integer type._ My qualification isn't necessary, though it isn't exactly wrong either (though the implication is possibly misleading.)

Comment: `SSIZE_MIN` doesn't exist, at least on my machine (Debian 9, GCC 8.3, glibc 2.28), and the best reason that comes to my mind is that `ssize_t` only guarantees to be able to hold the negative `-1`: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html

Also that text doesn't reference any `SSIZE_MIN` but has a `SSIZE_MAX`, so I guess `SSIZE_MIN` doesn't exist anywhere.

BTW, I have defined a macro in my library `#define SSZ_MIN ((ssize_t)-1)`

Answer (score 2):

There's a few APIs that come to mind which use the maximum signed or unsigned integer value as a sentinel value. For example, C++'s [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method returns `std::string::npos` if the value given to `find()` could not be found within the string, and `std::string::npos` is equal to `(std::string::size_type)-1`.

Similarly, on iOS and OS X, `NSArray`'s [indexOfObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:) method return `NSNotFound` when the object cannot be found in the array. Surprisingly, `NSNotFound` is actually defined to `NSIntegerMax`, which is either `INT_MAX` for 32-bit platforms or `LONG_MAX` for 64-bit platforms, even though `NSArray` indexes are typically `NSUInteger` (which is either `unsigned int` for 32-bit platforms or `unsigned long` for 64-bit platforms).

It does mean that there will be no distinction between “not found” and “element number 18,446,744,073,709,551,615” (for 64-bit systems), but whether that is an acceptable trade off is up to you.

An alternative is to have the function return the index through a pointer argument and have the function's return value indicate success or failure, e.g.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool linearSearch(const int array[], int val, size_t size, size_t *index)
{
    // find value and then

    if (found)
    {
        *index = indexOfFoundItem;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        *index = 0; // optional, in some cases, better to leave *index untouched
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to return negative values and still have some notion of a size type you use `ssize_t`. gcc and clang both complain but the following compiles. Note, some of the following is undefined behavior...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>  

size_t foo() {
  return -1;
}

void print_bin(uint64_t num, size_t bytes);
void print_bin(uint64_t num, size_t bytes) {
  int i = 0;
  for(i = bytes * 8; i > 0; i--) {
    (i % 8 == 0) ? printf("|") : 1;
    (num & 1)    ? printf("1") : printf("0");
    num >>= 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void){  
   long int x = 0;
   printf("%zu\n", foo());
   printf("%ld\n", foo());
   printf("%zu\n", ~(x & 0)); 
   printf("%ld\n", ~(x & 0));

   print_bin((~(x & 0)), 8);

}
```

The output is

```
18446744073709551615
-1
18446744073709551615
-1
|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111
```

I'm on a 64bit machine. The following in binary

```
|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111
```

can mean `-1` or `18446744073709551615`, it depends on context ie in what way the type that has that binary representation is being used.